# GET Request in client to Express server only getting response as text/html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, express, fetch

I have a react app on an express server. I'm making a GET request to the server from the client using fetch and the response is coming back as Content-Type text/html when I'm on chrome but application/json when I try in Postman. I want it as JSON.

**Postman Response:**

[image: Postman response]

**Network Tab in chrome when called from a button:**

[image: Network tab in chrome]

I've tried changing the content type in the express request.

```
app.get('/spotify/search-track', (req,res) => {
    spotify.searchTrack(req.query.name).then(function(result)
    {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

React GET request:

```
fetch('/api/spotify/search-tracks?name=' + val, 
{
     method: "GET",
     data: null,
     headers : { "Accept": "application/json" }
}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
```

I'm also getting this error on Chrome - probably because the < is from the HTML.

[image]

Comment: You should also be able to send an object with a key value pair back to the front end. `res.send({ message: 'success', payload: result })`

Comment: Through the app on chrome it is only coming back at text/html, in postman it's fine. I've tried this and get the same results.

Comment: Have you tried a `JSON.stringify()` around the response object too?

Comment: Yes I've also tried this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`res.send(result)`
You can use
`res.status(200).json(result)`

Comment: Or just `res.json(result)`. 200 is the default status code.

Comment: I just tried this. The status is still giving 200, still text/html.

Comment: I would also try  `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');` before `res` or as middleware

Comment: This also comes back as text/html

Comment: @jackdewinter my last resort: adding `Accept` so it becomes `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');` and using `res.json(result)`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that the request is calling /api/spotify/search-tracks and the server is expecting /search-track. My bad there ;)